# How do I accurately convert ETH to WEI when sending transaction?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, metamask

I am trying to send `ETH` from one account to another but the conversion from `ETH` to `WEI` keeps giving me headaches. In this case, I am trying to send `0.11 ETH` but in the confirmation window, I get `313.59464925 ETH` instead.

```js
// This is my transaction code

await window.ethereum
  .request({
    method: "eth_sendTransaction",
    params: [
        {
          from: window.ethereum.selectedAddress,
          to: "0x4dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2dr9820C",
          value: String(0.11 * 1000000000000000000), // convert to WEI
          },
        ],
      })
  .then((result) => console.log(result))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

I have also tried using [BigNumber](https://github.com/indutny/bn.js/) but it doesn't solve the problem, I guess I'm messing something up. How do I accurately convert `ETH` to `WEI`?

Comment: Change `String(0.11 * 1000000000000000000)` to `"11e+17"`, or use `BigNumber` (or explain in your question how exactly you have tried using `BigNumber`).

Comment: BTW, not sure what you're expecting from `eth_sendTransaction`, but the result of that transaction should be a simple transaction hash, not an amount of ETH or anything like that. Converting that hash into a numeric value is pretty meaningless.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i prefer using [web3 utils](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-utils.html#) to have cleaner code and prevent unexpected bugs so with that you can write this:

```
value: "0x" + Web3.utils.toBN(Web3.utils.toWei("0.11", "ether")).toString(16)
```

Answer (score 9):

**In ES6 using node module ethers, you can convert Wei to Ether as follows:**

```js
import { ethers } from "ethers";
const WeiToEther = ethers.utils.formatEther(weiValue)
```

**Convert Ethers to Wei as follows:**

```js
import { ethers } from "ethers";
const EtherToWei = ethers.utils.parseUnits("0.11","ether")
```

**And to pass the ethers to your Function:**

```js
contract.yourFunction({ 
  value:  ethers.utils.parseUnits("0.11","ether")
});
```

Comment: This converts Eth to Wei, OP asked for Wei->Eth

Answer (score 7):

Are you using **ethers.js** with **hardhat?** If yes, to convert Ethers to Wei, you can use **ethers.utils** as follows:

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");    
let ethersToWei = ethers.utils.parseUnits("1", "ether");
```

The code above converts 1 ether to equivalent Wei.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, here is a one liner solution without `Web3 utils`:

```
value: Number(ether * 1e18).toString(16)
```

Comment: What is `ether` please?

Comment: The amount of Ethereum.

Answer (score 2):

A good suggestion found in [ethersJS documentation](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/troubleshooting/errors/#help-NUMERIC_FAULT-overflow) is using such

```js
ethers.utils.parseEther("1")
```